# Right way to group a stream into POJOs

Tags: java, collections, functional-programming, java-stream

I have a list of summary rows, which has few-rows-per-entity, where some scalar properties of the entity are repeated and there are two additional columns GroupName and GroupCount which are unique.

Basically this is the output of a SQL join, and the entity data is repeated and there is a unique group name, and its count in each row.

I want to stream this and collect it into an entity Dto which has the entity properties as well as a Map for the merged group statistics.

I tried an implementation using Collectors.groupingBy, but it still doesn't look right.

```java
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class DepartmentSummaryRow{
        private int id;
        private String name;
        private String groupName;
        private int groupMembersCount;
    }
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class Department{
        private int id;
        private String name;
        @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
        private final Map<String, Integer> groupCounts = new HashMap<>();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        grouping();
    }
    
    private static void grouping() {
        Gson g = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
        
        //Test data
        List<DepartmentSummaryRow> summaries = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=1;i<=50;i++) {
            summaries.add( new DepartmentSummaryRow(i, "name_a"+i, "g1", 3 ) );
            summaries.add( new DepartmentSummaryRow(i, "name_b"+i, "g2", 9 ) );
        }
        

        //Just group the summary rows
        Map<Department, List<DepartmentSummaryRow>> departmentsToSummaries = summaries
                                                                    .stream()
                                                                    .collect(
                                                                            Collectors.groupingBy( 
                                                                                    (summary)->{ return new Department(summary.id, summary.name); }, 
                                                                                    LinkedHashMap::new, 
                                                                                    Collectors.toList()
                                                                            )
                                                                    );
        
        //Merge the info into the departments
        departmentsToSummaries.forEach( (entity, sumaryRow)->{ 
            entity.groupCounts.putAll( 
                    sumaryRow.stream().collect( 
                                Collectors.groupingBy( 
                                    DepartmentSummaryRow::getGroupName, 
                                    Collectors.summingInt( DepartmentSummaryRow::getGroupMembersCount ) 
                                ) 
                            ) 
                ) ;
            } );
        
        System.out.println( g.toJson( departmentsToSummaries.keySet() ) );
    }
```

I am looking for some ideas for a better implementation than this for grouping a stream into custom POJOs. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

(Note: this itself has some bug.. for some reason the first grouping by my POJO doesn't group at all.. which is odd, as it has a good hashcode and equals provided by Lombok)

Edit:
Here's what the input looks like:

```
[
  { "id": 1, "name": "name_a1", "groupName": "g1", "groupMembersCount": 3 }, 
  { "id": 1, "name": "name_b1", "groupName": "g2", "groupMembersCount": 9 }, 
  { "id": 2, "name": "name_a1", "groupName": "g1", "groupMembersCount": 3 }, 
...
]
```

And here's the expected result:

```
[ 
  { "id": 1, "name": "name_a1", "groupCounts": { "g1": 3, "g2": 9 } }, 
  { "id": 2, "name": "name_a2", "groupCounts": { "g1": 3, "g2": 9 } },
...
]
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of how the final json should look like?

Comment: @always_a_rookie Added

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that the expected result may be retrieved only if grouping is done by `summary.id` (`summary.name` values differ), then the name of the first matching `DepartmentSummaryRow` should be applied to remaining `Department`.

So a minor fix to exclude `name` from `equals` and `hashCode` in `Department` should do the trick:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public static class Department {
    private int id;
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private String name;
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private final Map<String, Integer> groupCounts = new HashMap<>();
}
```

---

However, it may be better to use [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) with `merge` function and `Supplier<Map>` to achieve the similar result without using `Department` as a map key:

```java
List<Department> result = new ArrayList<>(
    summaries
        .stream() // Stream<DepartmentSummaryRow>
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                DepartmentSummaryRow::getId, // int id as key
                SOGroup::create,             // value: Department
                SOGroup::merge,              // merge departments by id
                LinkedHashMap::new           // keep insertion order
        ))
        .values()
);

result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

A couple of utility methods need to be implemented:

```java
static Department create(DepartmentSummaryRow row) {
    Department dept = new Department(row.getId(), row.getName());
    dept.getGroupCounts().put(row.getGroupName(), row.getGroupMembersCount());
    return dept;
}

static Department merge(Department dept1, Department dept2) {
    dept2.getGroupCounts().forEach(
        (k, v) -> dept1.getGroupCounts().merge(k, v, Integer::sum)
    );
    return dept1;
}
```

Output:

```java
[
    {"id":1,"name":"name_a1","groupCounts":{"g1":3,"g2":9}},
    {"id":2,"name":"name_a2","groupCounts":{"g1":3,"g2":9}},
...
    {"id":49,"name":"name_a49","groupCounts":{"g1":3,"g2":9}},
    {"id":50,"name":"name_a50","groupCounts":{"g1":3,"g2":9}}
]
```